# SignalR message from server to client duplicated

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am fighting a problem with `SignalR` in `MVC` application. I have created an `MVC 4` project based on `internet template` and instaled `SignalR nuget packet`. `Hub` class looks like this:

```
public class yourAppHub : Hub
{
    static Timer t;

    public yourAppHub()
    {
        t = new Timer(5000);
        t.Elapsed += Hello;
        t.Start();
    }

    public void Hello(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Clients.All.refreshPage("hello");
    }
}
```

And this is what I have on master page(`_Layout.cshtml`):

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var con = $.hubConnection();
            var hub = con.createHubProxy('yourAppHub');
            hub.on('refreshPage', function (message) { alert(message); });

            con.start(function () { hub.invoke('Hello'); });
        });
    </script>
}
```

When I am logging in I get 2 alerts every 5 seconds. Why 2 alerts? But if I go to home page, then go to contact form, then on some another page, alerts begin to continuously pop up. I can't get what I have done wrong here. I expect alert to pop up once in 5 seconds.

Comment: Just a hint - SignalR creates a new hub instance for each request, so even though you have a static timer you are creating new Timer instances and assign them to one static variable. Not sure if this is the root cause of your problem but this does not seem right.

Comment: @Pawel, yes I suspect that was the problem. On each instantiation there was a new timer. Thanks for useful tip!

Comment: i got the same problem , how shall i prevent it to create new instance each time

Comment: i need all request get the same result if it is in the timer time frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed this wonderful tutorial http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/826/server-side-timer-aspnet-mvc-signalr . It implements singleton and starts timer not in hub but in that singleton. Now it works as expected.